# persistence.xml and postgresql set 0 == false

Tags: postgresql, persistence, persistence.xml

We migrate our application from oracle to postgresql. And we have got problem because many question using 0 as false. And now we have got many errors that :

```
operator does not exist: integer = boolean
```

Its possible using settings in persistence.xml and define postgresql that 0 = false ???

PS I am using glassfish v3 and toplink as JPA

Comment: It appears you are comparing a boolean with an integer. The cast is not implicit, so you'll have to cast it explicitely.

Comment: yes oracle using 0 or 1 but postgresql true / false
Its posible easy migrate this stuff ??

Comment: It depends. Is it code? Only a few queries? Many queries? You could edit and add an expicit coercion. Or change the datatype while importing and (maybe) change it later.Or use a UDF to do that (but still edit) Or: add a default coercion to the pg-source (could be impossible, and very difficult, not for the faint-at-heart; the type system is robust but easy to break, IMHO) BTW: Please add a code fragment...

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that Oracle doesn't have a true bool type but PostgreSQL does.  As a result:

```
SELECT true = '1';
```

Returns 't' for true

```
SELECT true = 1;
```

Produces the error you are experiencing.  If you can change your persistence to compare with a quoted (i.e. unknown) type, that will solve the problem.

If you can't do that, you can create a custom operator:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION comp_bool(bool, int) RETURNS bool LANGUAGE SQL AS
$$
SELECT $1 = $2::bool;
$$;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION comp_bool(int, bool) RETURNS bool LANGUAGE SQL AS
$$
SELECT $1::bool = $2;
$$;

CREATE OPERATOR = (
    procedure = comp_bool,
    leftarg = bool,
    rightarg = int,
    commutator = =
);


CREATE OPERATOR = (
    procedure = comp_bool,
    leftarg = int,
    rightarg = bool,
    commutator = =
);
```

Then

```
SELECT true = 1;
```

works.....